# How can I modify specific armor values of items (with the console commands) in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was kind of disappointed the mask Morokei would not let me use the mage armor perk anymore, so I thought I'd find a way to mod it to have 0 armor.  Does anyone know how to do this, or if there is another way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's [a mod that makes certain unique gear enchantable](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=454) that was made to satisfy nearly the same request at the Bethsoft forums. It doesn't do exactly what you're looking for, which is to just alter Morokei to be a clothing item instead of armour. Instead, it removes the existing enchantments from a selection of unique items (including the mask) so that they can be custom-enchanted. The mask has also be set as a cloth item.

If you're good at enchanting and want to custom-enchant your Morokei, this mod will do it for you. If you don't want to mess with enchanting, then you'll have to keep waiting for a mod that just changes the mask to be non-armour.